# Information set of a linear code

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

I am trying to prove a couple of statements about information sets of linear codes, but i am having trouble with these proofs or i am not sure if i understand correct what i should prove. I would appreciate any hints or comments.

Information sets we define the following way: Consider a $\left [ n,k \right ]_{q}$ linear code $C$ is a subset of $k$ integers which are the coordinates of the linear independent columns of the generator matrix $G$ of this linear code.

- *Every linear code has at least one information set.*

I know that the generator matrix consists of $G=\left [ I_{k}\mid A \right ]$, where $I_{k}$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix and $A$ is some $k\times (n-k)$ matrix. Of course, the columns of the identity matrix are linear independent and their coordinates form an information set. Can we say that every generator matrix $G$ could be brought in the form above, so the set $\left \{ 1,2,...,k \right \}$ is an information set?

- *Consider the binary Hamming code. How many information sets has the $(2^{m}-1,m)$ Hamming code?*

My guess is $m$, since $m$ is the rank of the generator matrix $G$, but how can i prove it?

Could anybody help me with these statements? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The process of bringing a generator matrix $G$ to the form $(I_k|A)$ may necessitate (in addition to elementary row operations) a permutation of columns. This latter operation does change the code (the concept of *equivalent codes* enters the scene here). A more precise way of formulating this would be to reduce $G$ to the reduced row echelon form. After that we observe the set of positions of the initial $1$s. Those positions form *an* information set.

Comment: Please check the question about the Hamming code. A binary Hamming code of length $2^m-1$ has rank $k=2^m-1-m$. Its check matrix has as columns all the non-zero $m$-tuples of bits. Anyway, the information sets of a code are the complements of the informations sets of the dual code, so you can answer this question by calculating the number of invertible binary $m\times m$ matrices (that particular question has been answered many times on this site). I'm afraid there is no basis to your "guess".

Comment: I take some of the back. The invertible binary $m\times m$ matrices seriously overcount, by a factor of $m!$. This is because you get a different matrix by permuting the columns, but the information set remains the same when you do that. Sorry.